# How to generate a *.so file on AIX with CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake, aix, .so, .a

With gcc the newer CMake V3.14 build a shared library in an archive format with ".a" suffix on AIX platform. But we need a *.so shared file. One solution what I have found is to patch /opt/freeware/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/Platform/AIX-GNU.cmake by adding the line "cp <OBJECT_DIR>/lib<TARGET_NAME>.so <TARGET_BASE>.so".

```
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License.  See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.
 
 
# This module is shared by multiple languages; use include blocker.
if(__AIX_COMPILER_GNU)
  return()
endif()
set(__AIX_COMPILER_GNU 1)
 
macro(__aix_compiler_gnu lang)
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_RUNTIME_${lang}_FLAG "-Wl,-bnoipath -Wl,-blibpath:")
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_RUNTIME_${lang}_FLAG_SEP ":")
 
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_${lang}_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_${lang}_FLAGS})
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_CREATE_${lang}_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_${lang}_FLAGS})
 
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_USE_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES_IN_RUNTIME_PATH 1)
 
 
  if(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 7 OR CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION VERSION_LESS 7.1)
    unset(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OPTIONS_VISIBILITY)
  endif()
 
  # By default, module are .so and shared libraries .a in AIX.
  # As this comportment can be overwritten or misrespected we provides both .a and stripped .so.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY
    "<CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_${lang}_FLAGS> <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_${lang}_FLAGS> <SONAME_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME> -o <OBJECT_DIR>/lib<TARGET_NAME>.so <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES>"
    "<CMAKE_AR> -c -q <TARGET> <OBJECT_DIR>/lib<TARGET_NAME>.so"
    "cp <OBJECT_DIR>/lib<TARGET_NAME>.so <TARGET_BASE>.so" # <-- Patched line
    "rm <OBJECT_DIR>/lib<TARGET_NAME>.so"
  )
 
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE
    "<CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER> <CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_${lang}_FLAGS> <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_CREATE_${lang}_FLAGS> <SONAME_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES>"
    "strip -e -X32_64 <TARGET>"
  )
endmacro()
```

Is there another possibility to switch on the *.so file generation?

Comment: You could try pre-setting `LDFLAGS=-Wl,-brtl` (It works with `libtool`, perhaps it will work with `cmake` as well.)

Comment: Thanks to Brad King he has clarified that the configuration is not the same as on Kitware repository https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/v3.14.7/Modules/Platform/AIX-GNU.cmake. The CMake RPM package for AIX is misconfigured.